# Is there a semantic difference between toExternalForm and toString on java.net.URL?

Tags: java

The implementation of one simply delegates to the other, which suggests to me that there is a semantic difference between the two from an interface standpoint -- or at least, someone thought so at some point. Can anyone shed some light there?

Edit: I already know the implementation of `toString` delegates to `toExternalForm`. It's the first thing I said. :) I'm asking **why** this duplication exists - that's what I meant by "semantic" difference.

Answer (score 7):

The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) state this for *both* `toString()` *and* `toExternalForm()`,

> Constructs a string representation of this URL. The string is created by calling the `toExternalForm` method of the stream protocol handler for this object.

In other words, the two methods are *specified* to return the same value.

---

Why?

It would be difficult to find the real reason that `URL` API was designed this way.  The decisions were made ~25 years ago.  People won't remember, and meeting notes (if they were taken) have probably been lost or disposed of.

However, I imagine the reasoning would have gone something like this:

1. The `Object.toString()` method has a very loose specification.  It basically just returns something that may be useful for debugging.
2. The designers probably decided that they wanted a method that has a clear and specific behavior for stringifying a `URL` object.  They called it `URL.toExternalForm()`.
3. Having designed and implemented `URL.toExternalForm()` someone probably thought:

   > *"Oh ... now I have a good way to implement `URL.toString()`"*.
4. Finally, they probably decided to *specify* that the two methods return the same thing.

---

The decision to specify that the two methods return the same thing was made between Java 1.0 and Java 1.1.   (Google for the Java 1.0 and 1.1 documentation and look at the respective javadocs.)

This suggests that step 4 was done "after the fact" of the original implementation.  (We would need to look at the *original* source code and commit history to confirm that, and it is not available.)

Answer (score 3):

The OpenJDK code contains the answer:

There is absolutely no difference between `java.net.URL.toString()` and `java.net.URL.toExternalForm()` as `toString()` just calls `toExternalForm()`:

```
public final class URL implements java.io.Serializable {
   ...

   public String toString() {
        return toExternalForm();
   }

   ...

   public String toExternalForm() {
       return handler.toExternalForm(this);
   }
```

[Source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/URL.java#L986)

The question **WHY** is a different topic. Both methods have not been changed for more than 13 years. Also some Java 1.1 documentation that is still online indicates that both methods were designed to return the same result right at the beginning of Java. Most likely the `toExternalForm()` is the correct method to get a String representation of an URL and for convenience the `toString()` method just returns the same result as toString() is way more often used by most Java developers.